# Which one is good to use - Zoidberg or Term::Shell ( Perl Modules ) to implement the customize shell in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, cpan

I am going to write the code for my own shell which has some customized commands and i want to code it in Perl. I have found two modules on CPAN which can help me for the same.

1) Term::Shell ( http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Term-Shell-0.06/lib/Term/Shell.pod )

2) Zoidberg ( https://metacpan.org/pod/Zoidberg )

Which module shall i use for the implementation?
Is Term::Shell older then Zoidberg and lacking features then Zoidberg?

OR is there any other module which can help me better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you want.

If you want something a bit like a Unix shell, with built in commands like `cd`, and that will launch external programs like Firefox just by typing `firefox`, which you can then customize to add your own commands, then go with [Zoidberg](https://metacpan.org/pod/Zoidberg).

If you want to start with a blank slate and create your own commands so that you have a shell that just includes what you want and nothing else, then go with [Term::Shell](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Shell).

Personally though for the latter case, I'd use [App::Cmd](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Cmd) and write each command that I wanted my shell to support as an App::Cmd subcommand of my app. Then use [an approach like this](https://metacpan.org/source/DOLMEN/Dist-Zilla-Shell-0.005/lib/Dist/Zilla/App/Command/shell.pm) to add an interactive shell.

Comment: My requirement is to write the simpler shell which should be able to run Linux as well as user-created commands on basis of user privilege.